# Ajax как вернуть ошибку с сервера

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый, день помогите пожалуйста, отправляю на сервер комментарий пользователя, средствами ajax, скрипту answer.php. Как вернуть ошибку, если в комментарии например, недопустимые символы или еще что-нибудь? Правильно ли я догадываюсь, что нужно использовать функцию header?

вот моя функция jquery

```
$.ajax
({
  url: '/function/answer.php,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){в случае успеха},
  error: function (jqXHR, exception) {в случае ошибки}
});
```

Comment: в error должно приходить описание ошибки, там вы его и должны обработать

Comment: @Komdosh неа, error вроде бы возникает только когда запрос неполучился.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не совсем, когда сервер присылает код ошибки, например 400, 404 и т.д.

Comment: @Komdosh в принципе я об этом и говорю, запрос сломался.....но это все равно не тоже самое, что "если в комментарии например, недопустимые символы или еще что-нибудь"

Comment: а можно ли отправить свою собственную ошибку посредством header например что-то вроде header("В комментарии недопустимые символы", 400)? Или лучше вернуть сообщение echo("Ошибка" ) а потом в success проверить на соответствие if(data='Ошибка')

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов в случае таких ошибок, связанных с обработкой пользовательских данных придется на сервере в любом случае формировать какой-нибудь массив/json в котором будет поле со статусом. И в ajax  в success обрабатывать данные в зависимости от того поля

Comment: А кто вам мешает вернуть статус-код 400 через header?

Comment: ну лично я бы не стал смешивать стандартные коды ошибок со своими....все-таки тот же 400 - неверный запрос. А если  данные не проходят валидацию, то это явно не неверный запрос, а просто содержит некорректные данные

Comment: спасибо всем, очень хорошие советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю что лучше всего передавать результат валидации от сервера в виде json.
Не копируйте бездумно, я просто описал суть.

```
    function saveComment()
{
    //filter - очищает данные перед вставкой
    $comment = filter($_GET['comment']);

    //Записываем в БД или валидируем данные
    if ($db->comment_table = $comment) {
        $result = ['status' => 'ok'];
    } else {
        $result = ['status' => 'error'];
    }

        $json = json_encode($result);
        return $json;
}
```

Ну а потом средствами js в success(data) смотреть что пришло от сервера и выводить соответствующее сообщение об успехе или ошибке.

```
        success: function (response) {
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            if (result['status'] === 'ok') {
                Ура!
            } else {
                Не ура
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я только учусь, Подскажите, я так думаю что json нужен только когда возвращается массив?

Comment: Не обязательно. JSON - это способ форматирования данных для удобной передачи. Вы можете не конвертировать многомерный массив в json, а передавать готовую строку. 

Предположим:
$status = '{"code" : "12"}';

Comment: Если Вы сочли мой ответ полезным - буду признателен если отметите его как верный.
Спасибо.